# INSERT statement does not work with Citrus Integration framework

Tags: citrus-framework

We have started using citrus Integration framework for our API testing. I am trying to run SQL INSERT query on oracle database.

If we run SQL which has select keyword it just works fine, but if we want to insert data it throws null pointer exception.stack trace below . Could some please advise.

com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Test case failed

```
at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:221)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.DefaultTestRunner.run(DefaultTestRunner.java:189)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.runner.DefaultTestRunner.query(DefaultTestRunner.java:249)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTestRunner.query(TestNGCitrusTestRunner.java:170)
at com.consol.citrus.samples.DomainAPITest.sqlPMTest(DomainAPITest.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod(TestNGCitrusTest.java:130)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:100)
at com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTest.run(TestNGCitrusTest.java:58)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:208)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:635)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Caused by: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Missing keyword SELECT in statement: INSERT INTO CN_RATE_EXHIBIT (ID,RATE_EXHIBIT_CODE,DS,DSL,STATUS,RECIPROCAL_IND,START_DATE,END_DATE,TERM_REASON) values (seqCN_RATE_EXHIBIT.nextval,'Citrus_Inte_RE_Code','Citrus_Inte_RE_Code_DS','Citrus_Inte_RE_CodeDSL',null,'Y',to_date('01-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('01-JAN-4000','DD-MON-RR'),'O')
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.ExecuteSQLQueryAction.validateSqlStatement(ExecuteSQLQueryAction.java:266)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.ExecuteSQLQueryAction.doExecute(ExecuteSQLQueryAction.java:84)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractDatabaseConnectingTestAction.execute(AbstractDatabaseConnectingTestAction.java:62)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:214)

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace information tells me that Citrus tries to handle your INSERT statement as SQL query (SELECT). This happens when you mix INSERT and SELECT statements in one single SQL test action.

Please separate query statements (SELECT) from all other statements like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. Just use separate test actions in your test then. Also it is not allowed to use validation expressions in a SQL test action when using statements other than SELECT.

Citrus handles SELECT statements differently to others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the `ExecuteSQLBuilder` rather than the `ExecuteSQLQueryBuilder`.

```
public class ExampleTestDesigner extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource bookDB;

    @Test
    @CitrusTest
    public void exampleTest() {

        // query uses ExecuteSQLQueryBuilder and should only be used for select statements
        query(bookDB).statement("select ISBN, Name from Books");

        // sql uses ExecuteSQLBuilder and can be used for insert, update, delete, etc, statements
        sql(bookDB).statement("insert into Books (ISBN, Name) values ('1-84149-003-2', 'A Shadow on the Glass')");
}
```

Also check the [Database Actions](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#actions-sql) secion of the documentation